# Jquery datatables and jadcf: how can switch to external filter on window resize?

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

i am using jquery datatables plugin and yadcf.
All works well.
I want now that when the page width is under a certain value, the filters not are shown in header but move in an external div. When i resize again the page to full screen, the filter come back in headers.

How can achive that ?

Thanks in advace,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea,

Listen to the `column-visibility.dt` event of datatables (if you are using the responsive plugin for datatables / or just to re-size of the window itself, and try to init yadcf with `filter_container_id` usage for certain column

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I noticed that if i add the 'filter_container_id' to the column definition, even if i write 'externally_triggered: false', the filter in the header is not shown.
The filter in header and the extenal configuration are exclusive ?

Comment: the default value of `externally_triggered` is false (see docs), the only difference that `externally_triggered` does is that the filters wont affect the table until the `yadcf.exFilterExternallyTriggered(table_arg)` is called